# Dell XPS + openssh-server

Tags: apt, software-installation

I've just taken delivery of a Dell XPS 13 notebook with Ubuntu 14.04 installed. I set out to install SSH and found and installed `openssh-client` from the repositories with no problem. But when I try to install `openssh-server`, I'm notified that it can't be found in the repositories.

I've checked main, universe, and multiverse in the software center to no ail. Tried to get help from Dell tech support, got bounced around to Canonical support, only to be told that I needed to a member of some support program I've never heard of and am not particularly interested in.

Can any kinds soul please point the way to a successful `openssh-server` install?

Comment: Its in the `main` repo.. Did you run `sudo apt-get update` beforehand? If so, please [edit] the question and add the output of `cat /etc/apt/sources.list`

Comment: I've activated main. Get the following message with apt-get install ssh: "THe following packages have unmet dependencies: ssh : Depends: OpenSSL-server? E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken dependencies.

Comment: This Dell's installation of Ubuntu on my brand new XPS 13.

Answer (score 1):

Something is wrong with your package management.
Please try apt-get -f install

If this does nothing try

dpkg -i /var/cache/apt/packages/openssh-server*.deb

Post error messages and content of your /etc/apt/sources.list and sources.list.d/*.list files.

Comment: Curious. I had tried apt-get -f install last night but still had problems. Tried again this morning re:  your suggestion and, then, successfully installed both openssh-client and openssh-server.  Many thanks Uwe and others who've helped.

Answer (score 0):

Do `apt-get update; apt-get install ssh`

Comment: I get the error noted above.